# Can you put #includes in C++ headers?

Tags: c++, c, header, include

Is it allowed to add Includes in C++ headers? like in this example.

```
#ifndef SOMEH_H
#define SOMEH_H

#include <fstream>
int funcofsomekind(){
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("Stackoverflow.stack");
    myfile << "wolololol";
    myfile.close();
}
#endif
```

Comment: It's pretty necessary for a lot of headers, even if they don't define functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly add `#include <something.h>` in your header, and it is often done if necessary.

However, it is considered very bad idea to put any code in headers (like you did). At the very least, including function twice via header in different source files will lead to duplicate function definition at linking time.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than 'very bad idea' to put source inline in headers. What about inline methods, templates, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Literally all an `#include` does (from your point of view) is take the text from the specified file and put it right in the spot where you tell it to. So yes you can put it in a header and sometimes have to.

You could even do something like
`vector.txt`

`huge vector .....`

```
std::vector<int> v {
#include vector.txt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, however - anyone who will include your header will get a lot of additional code into his namespace.
what is more appropriate is to put the functions in a cpp file, and only include in the headers which which are required for the function prototypes -
for example if your header had a function like

```
bool is_open(ostream &o);
```

you will have to include fstream.

Comment: Actually, <iosfwd> would suffice.

Comment: good point :), that would be even better as it includes less things into the namespace.